# Programmatically setting ipad layout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ipad-2

I'm having kind of a funny problem.  I problematically now when i enter scene two set the frame sizes of my controls on scene 2 ( they are graphically laid out on the story card too), in order to handle whatever way they need to be drawn depending on device rotation. Testing has been on ipad 3 so far and there has been no issues.  But i have an ipad 2 tester and he says that when he presses scene 2 the program exits which to me mean's it's crashing. Now i don't know for sure now if the crash is related to this programmatic setting of frame sizes of controls like buttons and a text view, but its something that happens on scene load so i'm starting there.

I have two questions.  When can a programmatic drawing of a view crash the program and does the ipad 2 have a different screen area than ipad 3. I know one is retina but I've not thought that the coordinate system between 2 and 3 worked differently before. I did realize that tall ipods and short ipods had different space available this weekend but that never produced a crash probably because i programmed for a short ipod first and the layout was allays drawn smaller not bigger tell i updated it to support both.

Am i on the right path that it could be my layout drawing that causes the crash? I sent him a test build where i disabled programmatic sizing  of the controls(which means it wont support flip for now in that build) to see if my theory is correct but I wanted to ask here as well as i am hoping to fix this relatively soon.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He tried another build and it stopped crashing.  I had some controls at the top left that i realized i had not been programmatically setting location(they were in the right spot, upper left on flips) or had created referencing outlets.  I fixed it to set every control location.  I also changed it to programmatically change the view rather than wire a button to change views through the storyboard. There was also an issue that if you changed views before  connecting it would hang on my iPad 3 (probably because the socket wasn't initialized) and that might have caused him to crash.  I am not certain what the tester was doing.  I cannot be certain of what changes fixed it(though i've summarized the main ones) and a few weeks passed before i got ahold of him to try another build but i'm answering my question because  this is what i did to fit is and it's now working.